# Why is the output always converging to 0.5?

Tags: java, neural-network, processing

I was trying to solve a XOR problem, but the output always converged to 0.5, so i tried a simpler problem like NOT and the same thing happened.

I really don't know what's going on, i checked the code a million times and everything seems to be right, when i debugged it saving the neural network info I saw that the either the weight values or the biases values were getting really large. To do that I followed the 3 blue 1 brown youtube series about neural network and some other videos, too.

this is my code:

PS: I put the entire code here but I think the main problem is inside the bakpropag function

```
class NeuralNetwork {
  int inNum, hiddenLayersNum, outNum, netSize;
  int[] hiddenLayerSize;
  Matrix[] weights;
  Matrix[] biases;
  Matrix[] sums;
  Matrix[] activations;
  Matrix[] error;
  Matrix inputs;
  long samples = 0;
  float learningRate;

  //Constructor------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  NeuralNetwork(int inNum, int hiddenLayersNum, int[] hiddenLayerSize, int outNum, float learningRate) {
    this.inNum = inNum;
    this.hiddenLayersNum = hiddenLayersNum;
    this.hiddenLayerSize = hiddenLayerSize;
    this.outNum = outNum;
    this.netSize = hiddenLayersNum + 1;
    this.learningRate = learningRate;
    //output layer plus the hidden layer size
    //Note: I'm not adding the input layer because it doesn't have weights
    weights = new Matrix[netSize];
    //no biases added to the output layer
    biases = new Matrix[netSize - 1];
    sums = new Matrix[netSize];
    activations = new Matrix[netSize];
    error = new Matrix[netSize];

    initializeHiddenLayer();
    initializeOutputLayer();
  }

  //Initializing Algorithms------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  void initializeHiddenLayer() {
    for (int i = 0; i < hiddenLayersNum; i++) {
      if (i == 0) {//only the first hidden layer takes the inputs
        weights[i] = new Matrix(hiddenLayerSize[i], inNum);
      } else {
        weights[i] = new Matrix(hiddenLayerSize[i], hiddenLayerSize[i - 1]);
      }
      biases[i] = new Matrix(hiddenLayerSize[i], 1);
      sums[i] = new Matrix(hiddenLayerSize[i], 1);
      activations[i] = new Matrix(hiddenLayerSize[i], 1);
      error[i] = new Matrix(hiddenLayerSize[i], 1);
    }
  }

  void initializeOutputLayer() {
    //the output layer takes the last hidden layer activation values
    weights[netSize - 1] = new Matrix(outNum, hiddenLayerSize[hiddenLayerSize.length - 1]);
    activations[netSize - 1] = new Matrix(outNum, 1);
    sums[netSize - 1] = new Matrix(outNum, 1);
    error[netSize - 1] = new Matrix(outNum, 1);



    for (Matrix m : weights) {
      for (int i = 0; i < m.i; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m.j; j++) {
          m.values[i][j] = random(-1, 1);
        }
      }
    }
    for (Matrix m : biases) {
      for (int i = 0; i < m.i; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m.j; j++) {
          m.values[i][j] = 1;
        }
      }
    }
    for (Matrix m : sums) {
      for (int i = 0; i < m.i; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m.j; j++) {
          m.values[i][j] = 0;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  //Calculation------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  void calculate(float[] inputs) {
    this.inputs = new Matrix(0, 0);
    this.inputs = this.inputs.arrayToCollumn(inputs);

    sums[0] = (weights[0].matrixMult(this.inputs)).sum(biases[0]);
    activations[0] = sigM(sums[0]);

    for (int i = 1; i < netSize - 1; i++) {
      sums[i] = weights[i].matrixMult(activations[i - 1]);
      activations[i] = sigM(sums[i]).sum(biases[i]);
    }
    //there's no biases in the output layer
    //And the output layer uses sigmoid function
    sums[netSize - 1] = weights[netSize - 1].matrixMult(activations[netSize - 1 - 1]);
    activations[netSize - 1] = sigM(sums[netSize - 1]);
  }

  //Sending outputs--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Matrix getOuts() {
    return activations[netSize - 1];
  }

  //Backpropagation--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  void calcError(float[] exp) {
    Matrix expected = new Matrix(0, 0);
    expected = expected.arrayToCollumn(exp);
    //E = (output - expected)
    error[netSize - 1] = this.getOuts().diff(expected);
    samples++;
  }

  void backPropag(int layer) {
    if (layer == netSize - 1) {
      error[layer].scalarDiv(samples);
      for (int i = layer - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        prevLayerCost(i);
      }
      weightError(layer);
      backPropag(layer - 1);
    } else {
      weightError(layer);
      biasError(layer);
      if (layer != 0)
        backPropag(layer - 1);
    }
  }

  void weightError(int layer) {
    if (layer != 0) {
      for (int i = 0; i < weights[layer].i; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < weights[layer].j; j++) {
          float changeWeight = 0;
          if (layer != netSize - 1)
            changeWeight = activations[layer - 1].values[j][0] * deriSig(sums[layer].values[i][0]) * error[layer].values[i][0];
          else
            changeWeight = activations[layer - 1].values[j][0] * deriSig(sums[layer].values[i][0]) * error[layer].values[i][0];

          weights[layer].values[i][j] += -learningRate * changeWeight;
        }
      }
    } else {
      for (int i = 0; i < weights[layer].i; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < weights[layer].j; j++) {
          float changeWeight = this.inputs.values[j][0] * deriSig(sums[layer].values[i][0]) * error[layer].values[i][0];
          weights[layer].values[i][j] += -learningRate * changeWeight;
        }
      }
    }
  }


  void biasError(int layer) {
    for (int i = 0; i < biases[layer].i; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < biases[layer].j; j++) {
        float changeBias = 0;
        if (layer != netSize - 1)
          changeBias = deriSig(sums[layer].values[i][0]) * error[layer].values[i][0];
        biases[layer].values[i][j] += -learningRate * changeBias;
      }
    }
  }

  void prevLayerCost(int layer) {
    for (int i = 0; i < activations[layer].i; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < activations[layer + 1].j; j++) {//for all conections of that neuron to the next layer
        if (layer != netSize - 1)
          error[layer].values[i][0] += weights[layer + 1].values[j][i] * deriSig(sums[layer + 1].values[j][0]) * error[layer + 1].values[j][0];
        else
          error[layer].values[i][0] += weights[layer + 1].values[j][i] * deriSig(sums[layer + 1].values[j][0]) * error[layer + 1].values[j][0];
      }
    }
  } 
  //Activation Functions---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Matrix reLUM(Matrix m) {
    Matrix temp = m.copyM();
    for (int i = 0; i < temp.i; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < temp.j; j++) {
        temp.values[i][j] = ReLU(m.values[i][j]);
      }
    }
    return temp;
  }

  float ReLU(float x) {
    return max(0, x);
  }

  float deriReLU(float x) {
    if (x <= 0)
      return 0;
    else
      return 1;
  }

  Matrix sigM(Matrix m) {
    Matrix temp = m.copyM();
    for (int i = 0; i < temp.i; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < temp.j; j++) {
        temp.values[i][j] = sig(m.values[i][j]);
      }
    }
    return temp;
  }

  float sig(float x) {
    return 1 / (1 + exp(-x));
  }

  float deriSig(float x) {
    return sig(x) * (1 - sig(x));
  }
  //Saving Files-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  void SaveNeuNet() {
    for (int i = 0; i < weights.length; i++) {
      weights[i].saveM("weights\\weightLayer" + i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < biases.length; i++) {
      biases[i].saveM("biases\\biasLayer" + i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < activations.length; i++) {
      activations[i].saveM("activations\\activationLayer" + i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < error.length; i++) {
      error[i].saveM("errors\\errorLayer" + i);
    }
  }
}
```

and this is the Matrix code:

```
class Matrix {
  int i, j, size;
  float[][] values;

  Matrix(int i, int j) {
    this.i = i;
    this.j = j;
    this.size = i * j;
    values = new float[i][j];
  }

  Matrix sum (Matrix other) {
    if (other.i == this.i && other.j == this.j) {
      for (int x = 0; x < this.i; x++) {
        for (int z = 0; z < this.j; z++) {
          values[x][z] += other.values[x][z];
        }
      }
      return this;
    }
    return null;
  }

  Matrix diff(Matrix other) {
    if (other.i == this.i && other.j == this.j) {
      for (int x = 0; x < this.i; x++) {
        for (int z = 0; z < this.j; z++) {
          values[x][z] -= other.values[x][z];
        }
      }
      return this;
    }
    return null;
  }

  Matrix scalarMult(float k) {
    for (int i = 0; i < this.i; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < this.j; j++) {
        values[i][j] *= k;
      }
    }
    return this;
  }

  Matrix scalarDiv(float k) {
    if (k != 0) {
      for (int i = 0; i < this.i; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < this.j; j++) {
          values[i][j] /= k;
        }
      }
      return this;
    } else
      return null;
  }

  Matrix matrixMult(Matrix other) {
    if (this.j != other.i)
      return null;
    else {
      Matrix temp = new Matrix(this.i, other.j);

      for (int i = 0; i < temp.i; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < temp.j; j++) {
          for (int k = 0; k < this.j; k++) {
            temp.values[i][j] += this.values[i][k] * other.values[k][j];
          }
        }
      }

      return temp;
    }
  }

  Matrix squaredValues(){
     for (int i = 0; i < this.i; i++){
       for (int j = 0; j < this.j; j++){
         values[i][j] = sq(values[i][j]);
       }
     }
     return this;
  }


  void printM() {
    for (int x = 0; x < this.i; x++) {
      print("| ");
      for (int z = 0; z < this.j; z++) {
        print(values[x][z] + " | ");
      }
      println();
    }
  }

  void saveM(String name) {
    String out = "";
    for (int x = 0; x < this.i; x++) {
      out += "| ";
      for (int z = 0; z < this.j; z++) {
        out += values[x][z] + " | ";
      }
      out += "\n";
    }
    saveStrings("outputs\\" + name + ".txt", new String[] {out});
  }

  Matrix arrayToCollumn(float[] array) {
    Matrix temp = new Matrix(array.length, 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
      temp.values[i][0] = array[i];
    return temp;
  }

  Matrix arrayToLine(float[] array) {
    Matrix temp = new Matrix(1, array.length);
    for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++)
      temp.values[0][j] = array[j];
    return temp;
  }
  Matrix copyM(){
    Matrix temp = new Matrix(i, j);
    for (int i = 0; i < this.i; i++){
      for (int j = 0; j < this.j; j++){
        temp.values[i][j] = this.values[i][j];
      }
    }
    return temp;
  }
}
```

As I said, the outputs are always converging to 0.5 instead of the actual value 1 or 0

Comment: Today would be a great day for you to learn how to use your debugger.  For what it's worth, I doubt whether you'll get a satisfying answer to this on Stack Overflow - there's far too much code, and your question isn't really clear about _why_ you consider its behaviour to be wrong.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem, yeah I know... I've tried to debug this monster but it's kinda hard for because I'm in high school and pretty new to how neural networks actually work. My expectations are not really high to get answered, but I think I'll keep this post as a backup and try to rewrite the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrote the code and it is working now! I have no idea what was wrong with the code before but this one works:

```
class NeuralNetwork {
    int netSize;
    float learningRate;
    Matrix[] weights;
    Matrix[] biases;
    Matrix[] activations;
    Matrix[] sums;
    Matrix[] errors;

    NeuralNetwork(int inNum, int hiddenNum, int[] hiddenLayerSize, int outNum, float learningRate) {
        netSize = hiddenNum + 1;
        this.learningRate = learningRate;

        weights = new Matrix[netSize];
        biases = new Matrix[netSize - 1];
        activations = new Matrix[netSize];
        sums = new Matrix[netSize];
        errors = new Matrix[netSize];

        initializeMatrices(inNum, hiddenNum, hiddenLayerSize, outNum);
    }

    //INITIALIZING MATRICES
    void initializeMatrices(int inNum, int hiddenNum, int[] layerSize, int outNum) {

        for (int i = 0; i < hiddenNum; i++) {
            if (i == 0)
                weights[i] = new Matrix(layerSize[0], inNum);
            else
                weights[i] = new Matrix(layerSize[i], layerSize[i - 1]);

            biases[i] = new Matrix(layerSize[i], 1);
            activations[i] = new Matrix(layerSize[i], 1);
            errors[i] = new Matrix(layerSize[i], 1);
            sums[i] = new Matrix(layerSize[i], 1);

            weights[i].randomize(-1, 1);
            biases[i].randomize(-1, 1);
            activations[i].randomize(-1, 1);
        }

        weights[netSize - 1] = new Matrix(outNum, layerSize[layerSize.length - 1]);
        activations[netSize - 1] = new Matrix(outNum, 1);
        errors[netSize - 1] = new Matrix(outNum, 1);
        sums[netSize - 1] = new Matrix(outNum, 1);

        weights[netSize - 1].randomize(-1, 1);
        activations[netSize - 1].randomize(-1, 1);
    }

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    void forwardPropag(float[] ins) {
        Matrix inputs = new Matrix(0, 0);
        inputs = inputs.arrayToCollumn(ins);

        sums[0] = (weights[0].matrixMult(inputs)).sum(biases[0]);
        activations[0] = sigM(sums[0]);

        for (int i = 1; i < netSize - 1; i++) {
            sums[i] = (weights[i].matrixMult(activations[i - 1])).sum(biases[i]);
            activations[i] = sigM(sums[i]);
        }

        //output layer does not have biases
        sums[netSize - 1] = weights[netSize - 1].matrixMult(activations[netSize - 2]);
        activations[netSize - 1] = sigM(sums[netSize - 1]);
    }

    Matrix predict(float[] inputs) {
        forwardPropag(inputs);
        return activations[netSize - 1].copyM();
    }

    //SUPERVISED LEARNING - BACKPROPAGATION
    void train(float[] inps, float[] expec) {
        Matrix expected = new Matrix(0, 0);
        expected = expected.arrayToCollumn(expec);

        errors[netSize - 1] = predict(inps).diff(expected);

        calcErorrPrevLayers();

        adjustWeights(inps);
        adjustBiases();

        for (Matrix m : errors){
            m.reset();
        }
    }

    void calcErorrPrevLayers() {
        for (int l = netSize - 2; l >= 0; l--) {
            for (int i = 0; i < activations[l].i; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < activations[l + 1].i; j++) {
                    errors[l].values[i][0] += weights[l + 1].values[j][i] * dSig(sums[l + 1].values[j][0]) * errors[l + 1].values[j][0];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void adjustWeights(float[] inputs) {
        for (int l = 0; l < netSize; l++) {
            if (l == 0) {
                //for ervery neuron n in the first layer
                for (int n = 0; n < activations[l].i; n++) {
                    //for every weight w of the first layer
                    for (int w = 0; w < inputs.length; w++) {
                        float weightChange = inputs[w] * dSig(sums[l].values[n][0]) * errors[l].values[n][0];
                        weights[l].values[n][w] += -learningRate * weightChange;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                //for ervery neuron n in the first layer
                for (int n = 0; n < activations[l].i; n++) {
                    //for every weight w of the first layer
                    for (int w = 0; w < activations[l - 1].i; w++) {
                        float weightChange = activations[l - 1].values[w][0] * dSig(sums[l].values[n][0]) * errors[l].values[n][0];
                        weights[l].values[n][w] += -learningRate * weightChange;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void adjustBiases() {
        for (int l = 0; l < netSize - 1; l++) {
            //for ervery neuron n in the first layer
            for (int n = 0; n < activations[l].i; n++) {
                float biasChange = dSig(sums[l].values[n][0]) * errors[l].values[n][0];
                biases[l].values[n][0] += -learningRate * biasChange;
            }
        }
    }

    //ACTIVATION FUNCTION
    float sig(float x) {
        return 1 / (1 + exp(-x));
    }

    float dSig(float x) {
        return sig(x) * (1 - sig(x));
    }

    Matrix sigM(Matrix m) {
        Matrix temp = m.copyM();
        for (int i = 0; i < m.i; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m.j; j++) {
                temp.values[i][j] = sig(m.values[i][j]);
            }
        }

        return temp;
    }
}
```